# Delete only First Character in List<String>

Tags: c#

Suppose i have List string named `List<string> parts` with 3 Index [0,1,2] now i want to remove first character of every index how can i do this 
Input string :

```
Part[0]=".delhi"
Part[1]=".10.12.12"
Part[2]=".14.14.14"
```

Output string: `Part[0]="delhi"` like...

Comment: As a side-note, an algorithm that "removes leading dots" might be a safer way to do what you're doing.  It assumes less about the input in order to work (citation needed).  Notice how some answers have validation logic contained in there in order to make the "remove first chars" algorithm work properly.  Then again, maybe leading dots take longer to find!  idk, just a question maybe worth asking.

Comment: As per @DanRayson's comment: If you are guaranteed not to have nulls in the list, and you really just want to remove the leading `'.'` characters, you can use: `for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count; i++) parts[i] = parts[i].TrimStart('.');`

Comment: wanna choose an answer? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `linq` to loop through all the elements in the list and use `Substring` to return the string except first char.

```
parts = parts.Select(p => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p) && p.Length > 1) ? p.Substring(1) : p).ToList();
```

Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx) link for `Substring`

Comment: Or `parts = parts.Select(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p) ? p.Substring(1) : p).ToList();` (slightly shorter).

Comment: Note: You don't need the `&& p.Length > 1`, since if the string is one character long `p.Substring(1)` will return `string.Empty`. In fact, **this actually has a bug** because of that because it should turn `"."` into `""`, but it will leave it as `"."`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, length check I have put deliberately to return atleast one char string even it has `.`. It can be removed (Since SO has not mentioned any clause so I added a condition so that SO can understand what's happening in linq and substring method).

Answer (score 2):

You can do is

```
   List<string> part = new List<string>();
   part.Add(".delhi");
   part.Add(".10.12.12");
   part.Add(".14.14.14");

   List<string> filteredList = part.Select(x => x.Substring(1)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using a simple for loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count; i++)
 {
     parts[i] = parts[i].Substring(1);
 }
```

Comment: Linq would be my first choice but sometimes you need an in-place operation like this.

Comment: I would do it this way rather than using Linq, since from the OP it seems that they do indeed want an in-place solution. This needs a null check though: `if (parts[i] != null) parts[i] = parts[i].Substring(1);` - unless the list is guaranteed not to contain any nulls, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ for that:

```
List<string> result = Part.Select(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? s : string.Join("", s.Skip(1))).ToList();
```

Also you can create an extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveFirstChar(this string str)
    {
        return  string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? str : string.Join("", str.Skip(1));
    }

    //Or in c#6 and above use expression bodied functions
    /*
    public static string RemoveFirstChar(this string str) => 
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? str : string.Join("", str.Skip(1));
    */
}
```

and use it:

```
List<string> result = Part.Select(s => s.RemoveFirstChar()).ToList();
```

**[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fNC3s9)**